# Peut-on commencer une phrase par "pour la simple raison que" ?

Tags: ponctuation, constructions

> Le décalage aura beau être plus subtil, il sera beaucoup plus
>   frustrant. Pour la simple raison que nous étions beaucoup plus proches
>   et donc plus concernés.

Je dois couper ces deux phrases —*parce qu'elles sont beaucoup plus longues dans le texte d'origine*—. Pensez-vous qu'il soit possible de commencer une phrase par "Pour la simple raison que" ?

Comment: Si vous coupez les phrases de cette manière, la deuxième phrase n'aura pas de phrase principale; seulement une phrase subordonnée, ce qui n'est pas grammatical.

Comment: C'est peut-être dû au contexte (et totalement annexe à la question), mais les temps utilisés ne semblent pas en concordance.

Comment: @Chop merci pour ta remarque, je vais checker ça !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Écrire une phrase sans proposition principale est, je pense, déconseillé si ce n'est incorrect. Dans votre cas, il semble que vous vouliez un style correct sinon soutenu.

Pourquoi ne pas commencer la deuxième phrase par « (Et) ceci (celà) pour la simple raison que… » ?

> Le décalage aura beau être plus subtil, il sera beaucoup plus frustrant. Et ceci pour la simple raison que nous étions beaucoup plus proches et donc plus concernés.

Comment: Question de style, mais je commecerais plutot par *Ceci*, le *et* est plutôt une tournure orale.

Comment: J'ai aussi hésité et j'ai préféré la fluidité à la rigueur.

Comment: Séparer les phrases par un point-virgule et non un point ne changerait-il pas la donne ?

Comment: Il reste que l'on a une phrase sans verbe hors des subordonnées, même si celui de la principale est sous-entendu dans « ceci ».

Comment: @Chop : Ça ne me choque pas. Mais il n'est pas interdit d'être pédant : « Il en est ainsi… », « C'en est ainsi… », etc. Les autres tournures auxquelles je pense (« Celà s'explique par », « Celà est dû à ») entrainent l'abandon de « pour la simple raison que ». On rentre assez vite dans du travail de romancier…

Comment: @Chop: Le concept de phrase nominale est bien connu, le concept de phrase « prépositionée » l'est moins…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Vu sous cet angle, effectivement. Mais peut-on vraiment considérer que la proposition de styko entre dans la catégorie des phrases nominales ?

Comment: merci beaucoup pour vos conseils ! Super ta phrase Styko !